# How to make Hyper ledger Composer query case insensitive?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have a query deinged in hyperledger composer queries.qry file.

```
query checkOwnerUniqueness{
  description: "Select owner with given identifier"
  statement:
    SELECT org.acme.participant.Owner
       WHERE (idNum ==  _$idNum)
}
```

Now My query works if id number is abc123 and user search for abc123 but it fails if user pass on value as ABC123. However I would like query to respond with owner whether characters are entered in lower case or upper case.

I have already tried general SQL API's i.e. LOWER() and UPPER() but seems they doesn't work in the Hyperleger composer Query language. SO some can please help me understand on how to do this in Hyperledger Composer query file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first suggest that IDs are inserted in the first place (ie programatically) with the same case. Composer simply passes on the query to CouchDB's query language FYI and honours the case sensitivity at which the data was entered.

Are you aware that you can use `regex` to validate the ID field (see Modeling language docs [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/cto_language) ? - seems quite an important field to me (as opposed to say a surname field).

You can use otherwise `buildQuery` function (eg. with one parameter still) in your function - or if you insist in keeping the QUERY in `queries.qry` then supply two (lower and upper):

```
query checkOwnerUniqueness{
  description: "Select owner with given identifier"
  statement:
    SELECT org.acme.participant.Owner
       WHERE (idNum ==  _$upper ID idNum == _$lower )
}


var str = "joe123";
var lower = str.toLowerCase();
var upper = str.toUpperCase();
return query('checkOwnerUniqueness', {idNum: str} ) // ID passed in lower case
// OR
// return query('checkOwnerUniqueness', {idNum: lower, idNum: upper})  // upper or lower two parms
    .then(function (results) {
            for (var n = 0; n < results.length; n++) { // blah
            // process all objects returned in the query
            }
    });
```

Giving you alternatives anyway - I think I would make sure the ID field is always entered in the same case, just saying.

Comment: I also did the same and make sure that Everything is entered in uppercase or lowercase. But in case Somehow we get mixed  string i.e. "AbCd123" then it becomes difficult to match even using the method mentioned above.

Comment: if you use `regex` in the model definition, it shouldn't happen (as far as creating the participant goes)